# Android onkey - dispatchKeyEvent not firing

Tags: android, android-edittext, keylistener, keyevent, onkeydown

well, I've tried all the solutions I could find on stackoverflow and in other places, but the end result hasn't changed one bit: the only key that triggers the onKey event or the dispatchKeyEvent is the enter key on the virtual keyboard, and only if pressed twice. I cannot intercept any other key (there's a breakpoint at the top of the event and eclipse never stops on it, except for in case of the aforementioned enter). Beheaviour is the same on both emulator and real device. Any ideas? Thank you in advance
My code atm looks like this:

```
public class ChatWindow {

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    setSendText();
            //...
}

    private void setUserInput() {
    Intent i = getIntent();
    mChatInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UsrInput);
    if (i.hasExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_MESSAGE)) {
        mChatInput.setText(i.getExtras().getString(INTENT_EXTRA_MESSAGE));
    }
    mChatInput.setFocusable(true);
    mChatInput.requestFocus();
    mChatInput.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    mChatInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void  afterTextChanged (Editable s){ 
            Log.d(TAG, "afterTextChanged"); 
            if (mChatInput.getText().length() >= 1) {
                mChatInput.addTextChangedListener(this);
                //mChatInput.setOnKeyListener(this);
                //mChatInput.dispatchKeyEvent(this);
                mSendButton.setEnabled(true);       
            }
                    else 
                       mSendButton.setEnabled(false);
            } 

                    public void  beforeTextChanged  (CharSequence s, int start, int 
                    count, int after)
            { 
                    Log.d(TAG, "beforeTextChanged"); 
            } 

                    public void  onTextChanged  (CharSequence s, int start, int before, 
                    int count) 
            { 
                    Log.d(TAG, s.toString()); 
            }


         }); 

}
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
//THIS HERE IS NEVER FIRED UNLESS THE ENTER KEY IS CLICKED TWICE    
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN 
            && event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
    sendMessageIfNotNull(); 
return true;
}

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this issue? I'm running into the exact same problem using a galaxy note 2

Comment: I'm hardly an Android expert, but the dispatchKeyEvent function is outside of your class, shouldn't it be attached to an activity or key listener?

Comment: you also need to return true for Key Up events.  you should also post anything you want to do from inside `dispatchKeyEvent` and not execute it directly, because this callback occurs during the key handling.  you are also adding multiple listeners one time for each extra character watched inside your listener impl.

Answer (score 0):

dispatchKeyEvent will work only when the activity has focus