# How to override Soft keyboard keyPress event in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

I need a listener's to detect user interaction on my activity which has a fragment attached to it, for which i have overriden `diapatchTouchEvent()` which is working fine for touch event and hard key events, but it does not work for soft keyboard keypress.

To intercept keyboard touch events i have tried `onUserInteraction()`, `dispatchKeyEvents()`, `onKeyUp`, `onKeyDown` but none of them is working for softkeyboard.

Is there any other way to intercept softkeyboard events in Android?

for above query i have gone through these links :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25620981/3954050

[Android SoftKeyboard onKeyDown/Up not detecting 'alternative' keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217535/android-softkeyboard-onkeydown-up-not-detecting-alternative-keys)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to intercept keyboard event like done, or search or enter etc, in your edit text add a imeOption like

```
<EditText
   ..../
  android:id="@+id/myEditText"
  android:imeOptions="actionSearch"/>
```

And add an EditorActionListener to that edit text.

```
myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH){
                //Do something
            }
```

Comment: No i want to intercept key press events for all the keyboard keys on soft keyboard